# Dynamic GRUB menu

Tags: linux, grub

Ok, so I've got Ventoy set up on an external (USB) stick. On it I've put a Win10 PE .ISO file and a Zorin Core OS 16.2-r1 .ISO file.

That's because HP only puts out UEFI updates with Windows-specific files, and extracting the files from that and setting it up to work under Linux is a pain, so I used Win10 PE to update the UEFI. I usually run Zorin Core OS. The USB booting the Zorin .ISO is for doing full backups and emergency booting if I've crashed the system.

I've edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` so the Ventoy USB stick shows up in the Grub menu... so rather than hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> to change boot order, or entering the UEFI setup to change boot order, I just scroll down to the Grub menu entry, and the Ventoy USB boots. The Grub menu is on a 10 second timeout before it boots Zorin OS.

`/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry 'Ventoy Boot USB' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
insmod fat
insmod exfat
insmod ntfs
insmod chain
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 440A-1007
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
}
```

I was asked if I could make that dynamic... if the Ventoy USB stick isn't plugged in, it doesn't show up in the Grub menu.

I had the idea of putting a file named "GrubMe" into the root of the second partition of the Ventoy USB stick, then searching the drives for that file, discovering the UUID of the drive which contains that file, then adding that drive to the Grub menu.

Is this the proper way of doing it? If so, how does one search for a file using Grub scripting? If not, what is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Not doing dual boot, I'm running only Zorin Core OS. The Ventoy is used for: 1) booting Win10 PE (only for UEFI updates) and 2) for emergency booting the Zorin OS .ISO file and for full backups.

Comment: I've got fwupdmgr installed, but HP doesn't use that (yet). So I'm forced to boot the Win10 PE .ISO file whenever HP comes out with a UEFI update for my computer... it works well enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506022/create-a-grub-script-that-auto-detect-efi-systems-and-boot-first-one/74977789#74977789
does this help?